# IS NOT NULL for SQL Server CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, case

`Curr` refers to the current policy record, `previous` refers to the previous policy record.

I'm trying to figure out the ways to use IS NOT NULL

- 'Renewed Same Layer' - when the Limits of both current and previous matches ; attachements matches ;
- 'Renewed Different Layer' - when the Limits don't match or attachements don't matches ;
- 'Renewed Unknown' - rest everything; if Attachment has NULL values, then it still comes to this category

Renewed same layer works fine. But for few accounts, where `AttachmentUSD` of previous or current has NULL, I want them to go to 'Renewed Unknown' category rather than 'Renewed Different Layer'

```
CASE 
   WHEN curr.LimitUSD = previous.LimitUSD 
    AND curr.AttachmentUSD = previous.AttachmentUSD
   THEN 'Renewed Same Layer'
   WHEN curr.LimitUSD <> previous.LimitUSD
     OR curr.AttachmentUSD <> previous.AttachmentUSD
   THEN 'Renewed Different Layer' 
   ELSE 'Renewed Unknown' 
END AS 'Renewal Layer',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you expect:

```
case when curr.LimitUSD = previous.LimitUSD and curr.AttachmentUSD = previous.AttachmentUSD then 'Renewed Same Layer' 
when (curr.LimitUSD <> previous.LimitUSD OR curr.AttachmentUSD <> previous.AttachmentUSD) AND curr.LimitUSD IS NOT NULL then 'Renewed Different Layer' 
else 'Renewed Unknown' 
end as 'Renewal Layer',
```

At the moment, as you have the query, the else will never be reached because the first condition is exactly the opposite of the second condition

Comment: This approach is what I was exactly looking for.. worked like a charm:) thanks a ton!

Answer (score -1):

This is more of a high level since you are looking where to use IS NOT NULL.

IS NOT NULL is used because NULL is not a value in SQL Server. It is an unknown and therefore cannot be compared using an equality check to anything else. This is where IS NOT NULL/IS NULL comes in. It does not equal 0, false, or blank/whitespace.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, Value VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @table (ID, Value)
VALUES 
(1,'Test'),
(2,'Another Test'), 
(3, NULL)


SELECT * 
FROM @table
WHERE value = NULL


SELECT * 
FROM @table
WHERE Value IS NULL

SELECT * 
FROM @table
WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
```